# Blog site twitter issue

Tags: php, html, twitter

I have a blog page on the site I'm creating (php/mysql). I generate blog posts by date created, most recent first. When you click the title of a post, you are linked to that post's unique page.

Problem example:

I click the tweet button on the post "Happy Holidays" on the page mysite.com/blog. The url it tweets is naturally mysite.com/blog. I want it to tweet mysite.com/blog/Happy Holidays.

How can I force a custom url to tweet? Do I have to meddle with the JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply provide a link in the following way.

http://twitter.com/share?url=http://mysite.com/blog/link